# HERE Places API: not all items have PVID

Tags: api, here-api

I'm using HERE Places API.

Firstly I'm doing a search.

For Example this query :

```
https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/search?q=Test&at=35.6111,-97.5467&r=500&size=1&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&show_refs=pvid&pretty
```

According to this documentation ([Link](https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/topics/external-references.html#external-references__getting-access)) If I add `show_refs=pvid` to query string, in result I will get external `id` which I can use to query `lookup` endpoint.

But in result I get next response :

```
    {
    "results": {
        "next": "https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/search;context=Zmxvdy1pZD1hY2ExNzk3NC0zYzg3LTU5NzQtYmZkMC04YjAzMDZlYWIzMWJfMTUwNjA3NjMzMTYyMl83NDY3XzM4NTAmb2Zmc2V0PTEmc2l6ZT0x?at=35.6111%2C-97.5467&q=Test&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg",
        "items": [
            {
                "position": [
                    35.60369,
                    -97.51761
                ],
                "distance": 2756,
                "title": "Southwest Test & Balance",
                "averageRating": 0,
                "category": {
                    "id": "business-services",
                    "title": "Business & Services",
                    "href": "https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/categories/places/business-services?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg",
                    "type": "urn:nlp-types:category",
                    "system": "places"
                },
                "icon": "https://download.vcdn.cit.data.here.com/p/d/places2_stg/icons/categories/02.icon",
                "vicinity": "200 NW 132nd St<br/>Oklahoma City, OK 73114",
                "having": [],
                "type": "urn:nlp-types:place",
                "href": "https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/places/8403fv6k-d1b2fde0616e0326e321a54b88cd9f53;context=Zmxvdy1pZD1hY2ExNzk3NC0zYzg3LTU5NzQtYmZkMC04YjAzMDZlYWIzMWJfMTUwNjA3NjMzMTYyMl83NDY3XzM4NTAmcmFuaz0w?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg",
                "id": "8403fv6k-d1b2fde0616e0326e321a54b88cd9f53",
                "authoritative": true
            }
        ]
    },
    "search": {
        "context": {
            "location": {
                "position": [
                    35.6111,
                    -97.5467
                ],
                "address": {
                    "text": "Oklahoma City, OK 73134<br/>USA",
                    "postalCode": "73134",
                    "city": "Oklahoma City",
                    "county": "Oklahoma",
                    "stateCode": "OK",
                    "country": "United States",
                    "countryCode": "USA"
                }
            },
            "type": "urn:nlp-types:place",
            "href": "https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/places/loc-dmVyc2lvbj0xO3RpdGxlPU9rbGFob21hK0NpdHk7bGF0PTM1LjYxMTE7bG9uPS05Ny41NDY3O2NpdHk9T2tsYWhvbWErQ2l0eTtwb3N0YWxDb2RlPTczMTM0O2NvdW50cnk9VVNBO3N0YXRlQ29kZT1PSztjb3VudHk9T2tsYWhvbWE7Y2F0ZWdvcnlJZD1jaXR5LXRvd24tdmlsbGFnZTtzb3VyY2VTeXN0ZW09aW50ZXJuYWw;context=c2VhcmNoQ29udGV4dD0x?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg"
        }
    }
}
```

In response no object `references`

Is it a bug or not every place has this external id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am responding as member of the team around HERE Places API.

Yes, not every place has a pvid. That is why I would suggest using the Sharing Id instead. I realize that the documentation should be improved to clarify that.

The Sharing Ids can be obtained by adding `show_refs=sharing` to either your [search query](https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/search?at=52.521%2C13.3807&q=Hotel&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&show_refs=sharing) or a [place details request](https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/places/276u33db-19451d85dbbe41b4a45ddcf4983e9c10;context=Zmxvdy1pZD02ZWMxZmQ4Yy01YWE5LTUwM2YtOWQyZC05ODlhNzI5ZDA5ZDdfMTUwNjY4NTYwNjE4MF83NjA0XzU1OTcmcmFuaz0w?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&show_refs=sharing). It can be found in the field `references`. Once you have the sharing id you can you the lookup endpoint as you [intended](http://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/places/lookup?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&source=sharing&id=s-Yz1mYWNpbGl0eTtpZD0yNzZ1MzNkYi0xOTQ1MWQ4NWRiYmU0MWI0YTQ1ZGRjZjQ5ODNlOWMxMDtsYXQ9NTIuNTMxMDI7bG9uPTEzLjM4NDg7bj1IRVJFK0JlcmxpbitDYW1wdXM7bmxhdD01Mi41MzEwMjtubG9uPTEzLjM4NDg7cGg9JTJCNDkzMDQ0Njc2MDtoPTNjNTIzYQ).

Comment: Thanks for reply. Well, I have tried that request and search is fine, but I can't get how details request is working with sharing id... Before I have done request to `lookup` endpoint, but now you are showing example like `/places/v1/places/{sharingId}`. And it isn't working if I don't have context. Could you give me a link how correctly build details request. Thanks

Comment: Maybe the confusion caused by the 302 redirect returned by the lookup endpoint which most browser will automatically follow. That's why you see the /places/v1/places in the URL bar even though you fired a lookup-request by following my link. So you can do this in your application: places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/places/lookup?source=sharing&id=omitted and you will be redirected (HTTP 302) to resolved place details.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, now it is better :) Btw, I can get details about place just using placeId (not sharing id) just need include `&source=sharing` to query string. Is it also correct?

Comment: I would more rely on the sharing-id lookup. As it contains more information, it designed to survive id drifts in the place ids.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:

https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/places/8403fv6k-d1b2fde0616e0326e321a54b88cd9f53;context=Zmxvdy1pZD00YWU2ZWZjNi01ZjgzLTUwYTQtOTI4OS0xZjliMGMwNWY3NjBfMTUwNzA0NDE0OTc3NV84MTI5XzU1NDcmcmFuaz0w?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&show_refs=pvid

and

https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/places/8409q8yy-6af3c3e50bcb4f859686797b2be5773d;context=Zmxvdy1pZD00YWU2ZWZjNi01ZjgzLTUwYTQtOTI4OS0xZjliMGMwNWY3NjBfMTUwNzA0NDE0OTc3NV84MTI5XzU1NDcmcmFuaz0w?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&show_refs=pvid

On those two examples, the only difference is the `placeId`.

In the [docs](https://developer.here.com/documentation), there's not a single reference saying that the external identifier is required or existant for every place.

Since it represents an external identifier, I believe we could assume that it's not required.

And it's what we just saw with your place (`8403fv6k-d1b2fde0616e0326e321a54b88cd9f53`): this one don't have any external identifier.

---

Based on your comments, what you need is the information about a place.

So, after you run your first query, you should get something like:

```
{
    title: "Southwest Test & Balance",
    position: [],
    id: "8403fv6k-d1b2fde0616e0326e321a54b88cd9f53",
    href: "https://[...]"
}
```

With this ID, you could access it:

places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/places/**8403fv6k-d1b2fde0616e0326e321a54b88cd9f53**;context=Zmxvdy1pZD0zYTFlZjg5ZS02ZTY5LTUxYmEtYWFkYS1kY2UwZWMyNDdkMDBfMTUwNzEzNjUxNjI5N182NjExXzc2OTgmcmFuaz0w?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg

Or directly using the `href` information.

This response already is giving you the ID and URL to access all the info of a single place.
You don't need any other external ID or reference.

Comment: does this means that endpoint `/places/lookup` also marked as "Additional" can't be "executed" to every place?

Comment: As stated in the docs (https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/topics_api/resource-lookup.html), the lookup find a place by its foreign ID. So, I believe the best answer for your question would be: no, you can't lookup every place. You can try the lookup here: https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/places/lookup?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg

Comment: Is there any id which always exists that I can use with lookup endpoint?

Comment: This specific endpoint uses foreign IDs, which is not guaranteed to exist for every place. What's your real problem? Lookup places by a specific ID?

Comment: I need to receive detailed information about some place. Lookup endpoint looks fine for me in this case... but it only works with foreign Ids...

Comment: @demo And how do you define "some place"? Do you have an ID in your system? It's a latitude/longitude reference? It's by name/address? First you need to define clearly how you identify two different places. After that, with this information, then you would need to ask a new question: "How do I lookup a place based on X information?".

Comment: As I mentioned in question - firstly I do search (`https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/search?q=Test&at=35.6111,-97.5467&r=500&size=1&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&show_refs=pvid&pretty`) . Results I try to match by placeName and coordinates based on data that I have in db (also name + coordinates). After this I can get 0 or 1 item. And for this item I want to get all information that I can using `lookup` endpoint (seems like the most detailed endpoint). Well that's all

Comment: I understood your question was "Is it a bug or not every place has this external id?" so I answered that. based on your last comment I added the information to access the details about a specific place. I hope it's what you need. If so, please adjust your question accordingly to better explain what you really need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155952/discussion-between-demo-and-miguelkvidal).